# Some books about analysis ' properties of probability density and cumulative functions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, book-recommendation

I look for some books or references with the following properties:

1- Analysis ' properties of  probability density and cumulative functions such as limits at $+\infty$ or  $-\infty$ also Riemann integrablity;

2- Some special examples which applied in analysis more than statistics science. 
Thank you for your advice.